# How to send bytes data from golang to python using exec command?

Tags: python, go, io, stdin

Main.go

```
func main() {
    bytearray=getbytearray()//getting an array of bytes
    cmd := exec.Command("python3", "abc.py")
    in:=cmd.Stdin
    cmd.Run()
}
```

I want to send the byte array as input for the python script

abc.py

```
import sys
newFile.write(sys.stdin) //write the byte array got as input to the newfile
```

How do i send bytes from golang to python and save that into a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the process' stdin by calling [Cmd.StdinPipe](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.StdinPipe) on your `exec.Command`. This gives you a [WriteCloser](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#WriteCloser) that closes automatically when the process terminates.

The write to stdin must be done in a separate goroutine from the `cmd.Run` call.

Here is a simple example writing "Hi There!" (as a byte array) to stdin.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os/exec"
)

func main() {
  byteArray := []byte("hi there!")
  cmd := exec.Command("python3", "abc.py")

  stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  } 

  go func() {
    defer stdin.Close()
    if _, err := stdin.Write(byteArray); err != nil {
      panic(err) 
    }
  }()

  fmt.Println("Exec status: ", cmd.Run())
}
```

You'll also want to actually read from stdin in python:

```
import sys
f = open('output', 'w')
f.write(sys.stdin.read())
```

Comment: Ok thanks almost there I am reading byte array from a .wav file and sending bytes. I cant seem to save the data in the new .wav file in the python

Comment: You may need to open the file in binary mode `wb` ([read more about that](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)). Also, don't forget to close the file. If this is all your python does though, why not save the file using Go?